# Unit test Python method with database config as parameters

Tags: python, unit-testing

How to write unit test for below:

```
def processDbOutput(dbConfigObject, tuple): 
    dbConn = DBConnectionProvider(dbConfigObject.dbServer) 
    res=dbConn.excecute(......)
```

Want to write unit test for `processDbOutput` method accepting parameters.
And also mock the `dbConn` inside the method.

(update)
The processDbOutput method is target method for multiprocessing. So it is good practice to create and close db connection within the same method. (Correct me if I am wrong).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to test? If you mock `DBConnectionProvider` (and thus `dbConn`), you can test the parameters `execute` is called with. Other than that, it is diffcult to guess what you want to do. Best you show us your test code (even if it is not working) to better describe your problem.

Comment: Hi Bremen, can you provide me test code for above scenario. I am not sure how do i write test case to achieve this.

Comment: I want to test the processDbOutput method which accepting database config obaject & tuple to process. 
I want to:
1. db config object which is parameter (need to mock)
2. using the dbconfig object I create db connection (need to mock)

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. I understand that you want to mock several things (which you can do using standard `mock.patch`), but I want to know what do you want to _test_. E.g. can you write an example test with some assertions to show what you are going to test in `processDbOutput`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `processDbOutput` has two responsibilities. One is create db connection, and another is execute something.
It's recommended to split this function like below:

```py
def connectDb(dbConfigObject):
    return DBConnectionProvider(dbConfigObject.dbServer)

def executeDb(dbConn, tuple):
    res=dbConn.execute(......)
```

Then, you can test `executeDb` with mock, `dbConn`.

If you are re-structuring your code for testing, your code will be more beautiful.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated question based on multiprocessing aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I think that 정도유's answer can still apply. I still think the answer is dependency injection, but I would inject a function to initialize the connection:

```
def connectDb(dbConfigObject):
    return DBConnectionProvider(dbConfigObject.dbServer)

def executeDb(initializeDB, tuple):
    dbConn = initializeDB()
    res=dbConn.execute(......)
```

This enables your test to provide a dummy `dbConn` object for unit testing instead of patching. Then your production code can use `DBConnectionProvider()` directly:

```
def test_executeDb(self):
   m = MagicMock()
   # configure m.execute.return_value, etc
   def initialize_stub():
       return m

   executeDb(initialize_stub, m)
   # assertion
```